# How does Github work with Circl-CI when Circle CI skip test?

Tags: github, circleci-2.0

Now I'm using Github and Circle-CI. And Git flow is simple, after unit test on Circle-CI is done properly, pull request is accepted and merged into master branch.
In specific branch names, Circle-CI skips test. However Github doesn't allow to merge into master until unit-test is done.
How can I manage this situation?? Sometimes I wanna merge something into master without test on Circle CI.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has an option to allow admins to override that restriction. You'd need to use that.

Regardless, it never hurts to test everything.